# Redirect customer login/register success to checkout Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.2, login, redirect

I am creating a module for redirect login/register success to checkout if customer has some items on quote but that's not working.

If I stop the event with that `die;` on `Observer/Redirect.php` above that redirect works, but I need continue for merge quotes.

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="customer_login">
       <observer name="lima_customer_login_redirect" instance="Lima\CustomerLoginRedirect\Observer\Redirect" />
   </event>
</config>
```

/Observer/Redirect.php

```
<?php
namespace Lima\CustomerLoginRedirect\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context;

class Redirect implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_objectManager;
  protected $_quote;
  protected $_responseFactory;
  protected $_url;
  protected $_scopeConfig;

  public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
  ) {
    $this->_quote= $quoteFactory;
    $this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
  }

  public function execute(Observer $observer)
  {
    $module_status = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('customer_login_redirect/redirect/status', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    if($module_status){
      $cart = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
      $quote = $cart->getQuote();
      $totalItems = count($quote->getAllItems());

      if($totalItems > 0){
        $redirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('onepagecheckout');
      }else{
        $redirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('/');
      }
      $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
      // die;
      return $this;
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using  `customer_login` event,  suggesting to you implement Plugin on class [**Magento\Checkout\Model\Session**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php#L16) .

Implement after plugin method on method [**loadCustomerQuote**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php#L320), From where you have to set the  `setBeforeAuthUrl` for the customer session.

As per as, Magento if you set your **desired URL** to `setBeforeAuthUrl`, then after login Magento automatically redirect method that  **desired URL**.

Most of the important point, Magento merge **customer existing quote object** with **the current quote which is created before login quote login**  using [**loadCustomerQuote**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php#L320) using event [`customer_login`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/etc/frontend/events.xml#L9-L11).

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="loadCustomerQuote" instance="Magento\Checkout\Observer\LoadCustomerQuoteObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="customer_logout">
        <observer name="unsetAll" instance="Magento\Checkout\Observer\UnsetAllObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

So, now lets create a plugin.

**First define plugin via `di.xml` at  `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Session">
        <plugin name="set_redirection_url_if_have quote" type="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\LoginRedirection" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin class `LoginRedirection.php`  at `app/code{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\LoginRedirection`

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin;
class LoginRedirection
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    public function afterLoadCustomerQuote(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $subject,
        $result
    )
    {
        $quote = $subject->getQuote();
        if(count($quote->getAllItems())>0){
            $this->customerSession
                ->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('onepagecheckout/index/index'));
        }

    }
```

**Also, this module should have:**

1. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`.
2. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
3. . `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/registration.json`.

Note that:

Donot forgot to '

- do Cache flush `php bin/magento cache:flush`.
- Di compile `php bin/magento di:compile`.

**Aftre the changes .**

Comment: As I know, the `composer.json` used for the module which is 'under' `vendor` folder.

Comment: No,it is always need for   all module

Comment: What is the purpose of `composer.json` when we put it under app folder?

Comment: Khoa TruongDinh, i  don't have enough knowledge. But it is required and a required file.

Comment: Work like a charm, thank you. Ps, my module has all scrtucture unless composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution at [https://meetanshi.com/blog/redirect-customer-login-or-registration-success-to-checkout-in-magento-2/](https://meetanshi.com/blog/redirect-customer-login-or-registration-success-to-checkout-in-magento-2/.) and it worked fine for me.